# How to update Column of one CTE with another CTE in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I Have two CTE let's say A and B, and I want to update a column of A with CTE B.

```sql
WITH cte_A AS ( SELECT X, 0 AS Y from table_1 -- Some complex logic for Y that is why updating with other CTE )

UPDATE cte_A  SET Y = (
WITH CTE_B AS (SELECT Y FROM table_2 )
SELECT Y FROM CTE_B WHERE CTE_B.ID =  cte_A.ID
)

SELECT * FROM cte_A
```

I am getting errors like missing SELECT keyword in oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `UPDATE` a query; you `UPDATE` a table (or a view). However, you don't need to update it, you just need to **display** data from the two sources.

What you can do is use `JOIN` the two tables and instead of selecting `*` from `CTE_A` select `Y` from `CTE_B` and the other columns from `CTE_A` (and given your logic you appear to be using an `OUTER JOIN`):

```sql
WITH cte_A (id, x, y) AS (
  SELECT id, x, 0 from table_1
),
CTE_B (id, y) AS (
  SELECT id, y FROM table_2
)
SELECT a.id,
       a.x,
       b.y
FROM   CTE_A a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_B b
       ON b.ID =  a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't; a CTE is just another way of writing a subquery. You can't update a subquery; you update tables (in most cases), rarely views, but subqueries - nope.

In your case, you'd actually update `table_1`. `merge` might be a good choice:

```
MERGE INTO table_1 a
     USING table_2 b
        ON (a.id = b.id)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET a.y = b.y;
```

OK, I understand that there's some "complex logic" involved so the query might need to be modified, but - that's the general idea.